# Can you use SignalR with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I am trying to put together a SignalR app. Totally new to it, so following the MS tutorial, but have fallen at the first hurdle!

I can't add the SignalR Hub Class (v2) as described in this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

I am using VS2012, so this may be the reason I can't see it in the menu, or if I look in Add New Item...

The package installed fine, and I can see it in the package manager, but I can't add the hub class.

Comment: What did you do for these _// Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  _ and _<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just create an empty class instead & copy the source and references for the hub class.

Comment: Pretty obvious really! Thanks - ashamed to say it had me stumped!

Comment: I only know as I did the same tutorial last week. It's amazing how quick it is to get a chat application up & running with signalr. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want Visual Studio 2012 to show you the **SignalR Hub Class (v2)** template in the **Add | New Item** dialog, you can follow these instructions shown in the same [tutorial page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) (they are not easy to catch, I didn't see them the first time either):

> ### Using Visual Studio 2012 with this tutorial
>
> To use Visual Studio 2012 with this tutorial, do the following:
>
> - Update your [Package Manager](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget) to the latest version.
> - Install the [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
> - In the Web Platform Installer, search for and install **ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012**. This will install Visual Studio templates for SignalR classes such as **Hub**.
> - Some templates (such as **OWIN Startup Class**) will not be available; for these, use a **Class** file instead.

In my case, the **Web Platform Installer** didn't find the **ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012**, so I had to download them directly from the web. You can download the installer from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532) (I used the **AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe** file).

### Important Note

The templates don't appear on the **Visual C# | Web | SignalR** node as mentioned in the tutorial (there is no **SignalR** node on the **New Item** dialog box in Visual Studio 2012, as far as I can note), but they appear nonetheless in the **Visual C# | Web** node.